# how to set lower bound thresholds for New Relic plugin alerts

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

Wow! New Relic plugins are awesome! They allow me get alerts for all kinds of new data by writing a simple plugin. I'm trying to get an alert when my router's throughput drops, but I can only see how to set an upper bound for alerting. How to do I get an alert when my router's throughput drops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently alerting is only available for situations where the number increases past a threshold.

In a situation like this, you may want to monitor for the drops in throughput in the inverse, or do some math to calculate the variance from the expected throughput.

For example:

```
if throughput-75 < 0 report metric abs(throughput-75)
else report metric 0
```

This is just one example of the many creative ways you could achieve the desired results.